# Any general purpose NPAPI plugin to invoke external download tools?

Tags: plugins, browser, npapi

I am looking for a general purpose NPAPI plugin that can used to invoke GetRight/FlashGet/OrbitDownloader/InternetDownloadManager/etc.

Has anyone written that already? It's like FlashGot for NPAPI browsers.

Answer (score 1):

NPAPI plugins are for embedding alternative content into a page, not for generally extending the browser with new functionality.

What you are looking for are extension or addons (sadly and confusingly also sometimes called plugins) and those are mostly [browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)-[specific](http://pimpmysafari.com/) - search first before writing your own.

Comment: Addons are browser specific and they can not to do anything outside a browser box e.g. call an external download manager.

That why a plugin must be used, dude.

Comment: @est: I already said they are browser-specific and also that plugins are not the right tool for the job - you'd have to embed/inject them in every page, can't extend the UI page- or browser-wide, ... FlashGot by the way *is* an extension. *Sidenote: i am not anyones "dude"*.

Comment: Oh I get it. You mean I have to write an addon for each of these browsers, right?

But what I am looking for is a NPAPI plugin to rule them all, so that I don't have to write a damn addon for every NPAPI-compatible new browser that comes out in the future.

Comment: @est: Plugins *can't do* what you are looking for. They can't hook into the browsers UI and would have to be embedded in every page via tags.

Comment: Then what alternative technology do you suggest? 

AFAIK some web scrapper software like this one http://cn.wizbrother.com/wizknowledge/copy.js use `<embed type='application/x-wizbrother-wizknowledge-ax' width='100' height='20' "+params+"></embed>` to collect data from browsers. You don't call that a plugin?

Comment: @est: You can't get around extensions in this case. Collecting data from browsers is a very different case - you have control over the pages it has to be embedded into and you don't need to hook into the browsers UI actions.

Comment: @gf

If you ever looked into any modern download tool, it's quite complicated. You do not only need to pass URL to an external program, but also Referer, user-agent and cookie. 

I don't see you can implement this using only addon/extension without any plugin functionality.

Comment: @gf AFAIK there is no way to invoke an external program in Chrome except NPAPI for the moment.

Comment: @est: I don't see how you could implement this *using only plugins*. If Chrome really doesn't have any way to invoke an external program yet you might need to inject plugins as a workaround - there is still no way around using extensions.

Comment: @gf

Plugins are scripted using javascript of course. But the *only* problem I am facing is javascript in browsers can not get out of the browser box. Thus the quesion :)

Comment: @est: Ah, now i get you. You want to solve the sand-boxing problem of some browsers via an NPAPI plugin. I am not aware of any existing one, if you start writing your own consider using FireBreath (http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/). It already takes care of the platform details for plugins on Win, Linux and OSX - though OSX 64bit enviroments are still a bit flaky.